# how to call aspx file as popup window on MVC?

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

i need to open aspx file on MVC application as a pop window,i tried MVC

> MVC popup code:

```
window.open('/Scan/pop', '_blank', 'left=100,top=100,width=400,height=300,toolbar=1,resizable=0');
```

> aspx popup code:

```
window.open('http://localhost:58158/Views/Scan/pdf.aspx' + '?id=' + id, '', 'width=800, height=650, top=0, left=250, status=0,toolbar=0');
```

how to open aspx file as pop window in MVC?.
**one more thing why should i call aspx page means that page having existing application code so unable to skip that page.**

note:- MVC window.open working fine, aspx only not open

Comment: note:- MVC window.open working Fine.

Comment: for starters.... you don't have the '_blank' in your aspx code, and they're opening different URL's. Also please explain in what way it doesn't work.

Comment: i just added this code in RouteConfig file,  
routes.MapPageRoute("Default2", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", "~/WebForms/AspForms/pdf.aspx");                                                         now it is open as popup, but if there is more aspx files means how to configure for common code?.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't have to fiddle with RouteConfig. Did you try the suggestions in my first comment?